# Install of nodemailer results in module not found errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodemailer

I have a reactJS application where I am trying to install nodemailer so I can send out conformation emails from within the application.  This is an already existing application that is 100% functional and the email confirmations will be new functionality that I need to add.

My tree structure for the application on my development machine looks like this:
C drive
|_JRS
|_Accu_01
|_React

My package.json file is in c:\jrs\accu_01\react

I issued the npm install nodemailer from a command prompt while in the c:\jrs\accu_01\react folder.  The install ran fine.  I can still execute the npm start command and my application starts up without any issues.

I then add the following code in the componentWillMount() section of my home.js file:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
```

I am using Visual Studio Code to develop this application and when I hover my mouse over 'nodemailer', the studio shows me

```
module "C:/Users/jonat/AppData/Local/Microsoft/TypeScript/3.7/node_modules/@types/nodemailer/index"
```

And when I issue the npm start command, I get a bunch of module not found errors.  Here are some of them:

```
ERROR in ./~/nodemailer/lib/sendmail-transport/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 
'c:\jrs\Accu_01\React\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\sendmail-transport'
 @ ./~/nodemailer/lib/sendmail-transport/index.js 3:14-38
 @ ./~/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js
 @ ./src/screens/home.js
 @ ./src/screens/index.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./~/nodemailer/lib/shared/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 
'c:\jrs\Accu_01\React\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\shared'
 @ ./~/nodemailer/lib/shared/index.js 7:11-24
 @ ./~/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js
 @ ./src/screens/home.js
 @ ./src/screens/index.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./~/nodemailer/lib/shared/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 
'c:\jrs\Accu_01\React\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\shared'
 @ ./~/nodemailer/lib/shared/index.js 10:12-26
 @ ./~/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js
 @ ./src/screens/home.js
 @ ./src/screens/index.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./~/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 
'c:\jrs\Accu_01\React\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\mailer'
 @ ./~/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js 13:12-26
 @ ./~/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js
 @ ./src/screens/home.js
 @ ./src/screens/index.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./~/nodemailer/lib/shared/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in 
'c:\jrs\Accu_01\React\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\shared'
 @ ./~/nodemailer/lib/shared/index.js 9:12-26
 @ ./~/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js
 @ ./src/screens/home.js
 @ ./src/screens/index.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.js
```

Here is the contents of my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "sample-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "ebay-node-api": "^2.2.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.17",
    "publish-react-app": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-barcode": "^1.3.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "react-moment": "^0.7.0",
    "react-popup": "^0.9.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.0",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1",
    "simple-flexbox": "^1.2.0",
    "url-loader": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "es2015",
        {
          "modules": false
        }
      ],
      "stage-2",
      "react"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what I may have set up incorrectly?
Thank you!

Comment: Could you post your `package.json`?

Comment: I am unable to understand why you are using nodemailer in ReactJS? As per my knowledge, it is best to implement the mailing service in your server.

Comment: @AqibMukhtar My company makes use of office365 as our email server.  After completing an action in the reactJS application, the application needs to be able to send a confirmation of action email to a dedicated email address.  I had hoped to nodemailer to facilitate the sending of the data to the office365 email server.

Comment: @JasonNorwood-Young I have edited my post to include the contents of the package.json file. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that nodemailer is a back-end server. It needs to run on a Node.js server. You can't use it to send emails from the browser.

Depending on your use-case, you'd typically build a Node.js server that works with your front-end to handle the mailing requirements of your application.

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I moved away from nodemailer and moved to smtpJS. I am able to use this facility to send the simple emails I need to send.